# Google Earth Engine S2_HARMONIZED monthly composites

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am trying to get monthly NDVI composites of the Sentinel-2 harmonised collection (S2_HARMONIZED). I adapted a code written for this [same purpose but for the "S2_SR" collection](https://medium.com/@moraesd90/creating-monthly-ndvi-composites-sentinel-2-on-google-earth-engine-a5c2d49bc9ca) but did not work. It returns an empty image collection. Then I tried computing the monthly composites month by month -it works well but I would like to be able to do all at once.

Here is my attempt of computing one month at the time:

```
//define collection
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
                 .filterBounds(study_area)        
                 .filterDate(date_start,date_end);

var S2filtered = S2.map(maskS2clouds);
var composite = S2filtered.median().clip(study_area).multiply(10000).int16();
var S2filtered = S2filtered.map(addNDVI);
var S2filtered = S2filtered.select('ndvi');
var S2_clipped = S2filtered.map(function(img){ 
                    return img.clip(study_area)});

var NDVIcomposite = S2_clipped.median();
```

Here is the attempt to compute in loop in which I get

```
// /**
// * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
// * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
// * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
// */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
       
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Function to compute NDVI
function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
  return ndvi.rename('ndvi');
}

//Define first & last years of time series
var startyear = 2015;
var endyear = 2023;
var startmonth = 1;
var endmonth = 12;

// Compute beginning & end of study period + sequence of months & years
var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear, startmonth, 1);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear , endmonth, 30);
var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear, endyear);
var months = ee.List.sequence(startmonth,endmonth);

// Define collection, apply cloud mask and calculate NDVI
var S2Collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
                .filterBounds(study_area)        
                .filterDate(startdate, enddate)
                .map(maskS2clouds)
                .map(addNDVI);
                
// Create NDVI composite for every month
var monthlyNDVI =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) { 
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var monthly = S2Collection
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, "year"))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, "month"))
        .mean(); 
      return monthly
        .set("year", y) 
        .set("month", m) 
        .set("system:time_start", ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1));}); })
  .flatten());
  
  print(monthlyNDVI)
```

By the way, if I run the loop for the entire time series I get the error:

> User memory limit exceeded

But if I run one or two years at the time, there is no such error.